# Reabriendo:¿Cómo funciona el preprocesador de C++?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

Quiero reabrir [¿Cómo funciona el preprocesador de C++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78275/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-preprocesador-de-c)

Pero antes de tratar la pregunta debo tratar [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/78276/301). ¿Queremos una respuesta así en SO? Si no queremos una respuesta así no tiene sentido intentar arreglar la pregunta.

Para quien sí quiera una respuesta así:
¿Cómo cambio la pregunta? En su redacción me he guiado por otras que sí han sido bien recibidas como:

- [C# ¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla)
- [vb.net NullReferenceException: ¿Qué es y cómo puedo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76861/nullreferenceexception-qu%C3%A9-es-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-solucionarla)

No creo que mi pregunta sea más amplia que las anteriores pero está claro que hay quien piensa que sí lo es. ¿Qué cambio en la pregunta para que sea aceptable? Si es que hay que cambiar algo...

**Actualización**: He editado la pregunta siguiendo la recomendación de Mendoza.

Comment: Sin duda esa pregunta debe permanecer cerrada. La definición de Demasiado amplia dice: **Muy amplia - si tu pregunta puede ser respondida por un libro entero, o tiene muchas respuestas válidas, probablemente es muy extensa para nuestro formato.**, para lo cual tampoco considero que respuestas muy extensas sean válidas para la metodología de [es.so]. Para el caso de los dos ejemplos referentes a `NullReferenceException` se trató el tema el Meta y se decidió que puede haber sus excepciones en respuestas canónicas como esas dos.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no logro comprender porque mencionas a SO, entiendo que estamos tratando temas meramente de esSO, ¿es correcto?

Comment: @Flxtr Me refiero a SOes.

Comment: Sugiero convertirla en wiki de comunidad. ¿Qué piensas?

Comment: @ArtEze La pregunta ya no tiene casi nada de mi texto original, ciertamente es el resultado del trabajo de la comunidad y es razonable hacerla wiki. La respuesta no es el resultado del trabajo de la comunidad, pero tampoco me opongo a que la hagas wiki.

Comment: La dejo cerrada por votación.

Comment: @ArtEze Ahora mismo, las respuestas tienen (solo positivos): Cerrar: `6`. Editar y abrir: `4`. Abrir: `3`. `4 + 3 = 7; 7 > 6`. ¿ No debería abrirse ?

Comment: @Juanjo ¿Y si los mismos que han votado para "editar y abrir" son los mismos que han votado para "abrir"? No sería justo que voten 2 veces. Yo pienso que solo cuenta la opción más votada sin sumar otras opciones. Por cierto, yo he votado a "abrir" y a "editar y abrir"

Comment: @SEinfringescopyright Si aún crees que debería abrirse la pregunta puedes marcar la respuesta de reabrir como correcta y me comprometo a un voto de apertura. Si crees que debería estar cerrada puedes marcar como correcta la que tiene más votos.

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias, pero mayormente he dejado de usar el sitio como consequencia de los recientes acontecimientos.

Comment: @SEinfringescopyright Está bien, entiendo.

Answer (score 6):

Voto para mantener cerrada la pregunta.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza El **estado actual** ha cambiado. Sugiero dejar esta respuesta como la puso ArtEze.

Answer (score 1):

Voto para reabrir la pregunta.

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene, en el momento de escribir esto, 3 positivos y 1 negativo. Nótese que los negativos no cuentan (si contasen yo votaría negativo en la respuesta de mantener cerrada, cosa que no he hecho).

Comment: Para que todos sepamos qué estamos votando. ¿Aquí se propone reabrir la pregunta en su estado original solo o se acepta también reabrirla en su estado actual?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Para que quede abierta en la última revisión. Ahora que es wiki de comunidad, cualquiera puede mejorar el contenido.